# Simple Space geometry

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a tetrahedron. E is the midpoint of [AB] and G is the centroid of triangle ACD. 
1) Determine the intersection I of (EG) and plane (BCD) 
2) Prove that the quadrilateral BDIC is a parallelogram

I tried using converse of thales to prove that O(a point I added) is the midpoint of [BI] but there are missing information....then I asked myself what if [IE] passes through G....does that make it the centroid of ABI and therefore [AO) would be a median...but it didn't work....so now I'm focusing on how do I prove that G is the centroid of ABI

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advise...check out my edit...and again i'm new to this site

Comment: I see no edit made to the question.

Comment: I'm trying to prove G is the centroid of ABI but I can't figure it out!

Comment: Oh god! I just edited it. Where did it go...I'll edit it here...I tried using converse of thales in ABI so O (a point I made would be the midpoint of [BI]) but it didn't work...then I said what if [IE) passes through G... how does that help me...so i'm focusing now on proving that G is the centroid of ABI...in that case [AO) will be a median and O is the midpoint of [BI]...therefore BCID is a parm...

Comment: First time poster has listened to negative criticism and amended question accordingly, also included commentary relating to the OP's attempt. Surely the down-votes can be reverted?

Comment: I don't care about the downvotes that much...I know that they affect my question badly...but what I really want is a hint to my question...please could anyone help me and focus on the main subject☺☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT.

Let $O$ be the midpoint of $CD$ and consider plane $ABO$. From $EB=AB/2$ and $GO=AO/3$ it is not difficult to find $BO=OI$.

EDIT.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BO$. Then $EM={1\over2}AO$ and $GO={2\over3}EM$, whence:

$$
IO={2\over3}IM=2OM=BO.
$$
[image]

Comment: I didn't understand it well.. based on what? I mean I knew EB=AB/2 and GO=AO/3...but how did BO=OI...sorry for my unknowing :(

Comment: Ohhh...it's a hint...I got it...sry for my misunderstanding...I'll think about it

Comment: Ok...so you mean if GO=AO/3 and (IE) is a median passing through G. Then G is the centroid of triangle ABI. Therefore [AO) is a median relative to [BI]. Hence BO=OT. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Thanksss alotttttttttt....loved the way u gave me the hintttt :D

Comment: I've just read your comment better: probably your conclusion is a bit hurried. I think you should use instead similitude and also draw some other line (e.g. the parallel to $AG$ passing through $E$).

Comment: Mmmm... I'm an 11 grader in Lebanon. I don't think we took similitude :(  and they didn't give us space...but I adore maths...so I'm studying it alone :D but why is my conclusion a littile bit hurried...I'm so convinced and satisfied :)

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Perfect also! So coool...thanks guys...u r so kind...at first I had nothing...now I have many ways of solving this problem...really I appreciate that :D

Answer (score 0):

1. It would be easier if we select the plane ACD as the base. We let EG cuts the plane BCD at I.
2. Let M and N be the midpoints of DC and BC respectively.

[image]

3. In the extended plane (BCD), I’ is a point on that plane with CI’ // BD.
4. By midpt theorem, NM // BD // CI’. Then, by intercept theorem, BM = MI’. Further, DBCI’ is a //gram.
5. In $\triangle ABI’$, since AM is one of the median with AG: GM = 2: 1, G has to be the centroid of that triangle. In addition, since I’ is one of the vertex and E is the midpoint of the opposing side, EGI’ has to be another median. The important thing is EGI’ is a straight line. This also means EG cuts the plane BCD at I’. That is, I and I’ are the same.

Comment: Oh la la....just woww...liked it so much...thanks alot...the figure is drawn by geogebra right? I use it too

Comment: Sry for my delay...it took me a while to understand it :D...but it is amazingggggg